# Laravel project custom domain

Tags: laravel

I am using custom configuration of domain names for my laravel project *test* as *test.local* . When I ran this project as *test.local* in google chrome , it shows laravel homepage. But, when I go to any other routes it shows internal server error.
Can anyone have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just add index.php after the url, and then go to specific route

```
test.local/index.php/login
```

Answer (score 0):

So in your routes file eg. web.php, do this if you need to, this adds on a domain limitation.

```
Route::group(['domain' => env('APP_URL', 'test.local')],function () {
//routes...
});
```

In you .env file, define the app url, you may use https if required

```
APP_URL=http://local.test
```

After all, I would strongly suggest you to check you nginx file to see if you are pointing the path to the right one. And also check if index.php is added into the index file property.